# WordPress: pre_get_posts action combine date_query and meta_query

Tags: wordpress, meta-query

In my WordPress project, I have gotten some problem.

I have many categories. The categories have a child category name **New product.**

Currently, I have used `pre_get_posts` to get the posts list in **New product** pages. If a post which have **`post_date` > 2018/1/15** will be get in the category pages.

I want to add a custom checkbox `keep_product` in product which will keep product in **New product** page if **`post_date` < 2018/1/15** when it checked.

So I think the conditions should be **`post_date > 2018/1/15** OR **keep_product = 1`**

I try to create a query, but it seem `WP_Query` only apply **AND** condition for `date_query` and `meta_query`.

```
function pre_get_posts_function($q){
  //Code in here
    $query->set('date_query', array(
        array(
           'after' => '2018/1/15'
        );
    ));

    $query->set('meta_query', array(
      array(
            'key' => 'keep_product',
            'value' => '1'
        )
    ));
}
```

I also try to create a `posts_where` action, but It ignores category condition. The product which is checked `keep_after_60_days` checkbox will be show in **New product** pages.

```
function pre_get_posts_function($q){
    //Code in here
     $query->set('date_query', array(
        array(
           'after' => '2018/1/15'
        );
    ));
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'postmeta_new_releases',10,1);
}

function postmeta_new_releases( $where = '' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where .= "  OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'keep_product' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 1)";   

    return $where; 
}
```

Could anyone help me. I get mad with it in some days.

Thanks!!